# The meaning of [ and ] in constructor

Tags: dart

There is a usage of [ and ] in constructor like this:

```
class Host {
  Host([this.hostName]);
  final String? hostName;
}
```

What does it mean here?

Comment: Optional positional parameters: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#parameters